# OpenLdap won't retrieve the userpassword

Tags: php, symfony, ldap, openldap

My problem is that when i try to retrieve the value of the attribute 'userPassword' it won't work i'm working under PHP , the problem is that the attribute exist when i open Phpldapadmin i can see it , but when i try to retrieve it using this lines of code it won't work

```
$sr = ldap_search($ds,"ou=people,dc=powerm,dc=com","uid=".$login);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds,$sr);
$password = $data[0]["userpassword"][0];

$displayName = $data[0]["displayname"][0];
$num_tel =$data[0]["mobile"][0];
$mail =$data[0]["mail"][0]
```

the others attributes work fine expect the userpassword

can any one help ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the attributes you want returned explicitly.

```
$dn = 'ou=people,dc=powerm,dc=com';
$filter = 'uid=' . $login;
$attrs = ['displayname', 'userpassword', 'mobile', 'mail'];

$sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $attrs);
```

The directory may be configured not to return this security-sensitive attribute unless you explicitly ask for it.

It may also be that the attribute requires special privileges to access it - are you using the same credentials to connect to the database in your code as you did in phpLDAPAdmin?

The server may also be configured not to return the password unless it's over an encrypted connection - initiated using an `ldaps://` URL passed to `ldap_connect()`, or using [`ldap_start_tls()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php).

Comment: Wow. This guy *really* put effort into this answer. This has to be the single best answer I have seen on Stack Overflow lately. If I ever need to get the LDAP password I will totally use this answer because it is great and does all the things. 10/10 would upvote again.

Comment: Still have the same problem when using your code , as i said it's shows me all the attributes expect the userpassword , ihave the same configuration on the server side as my collegue , he can retrieve the userpassword and me i can't so i don't think it's a configuration problem